# Slow system slow and normal after restart

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd

I have a problem with my computer. It is slow at startup and saying that windows explorer stopped responding. After a restart, my computer works fine. I watched the boot message and it is slow with auto-detecting ahci port and a SATA port4 device error. I checked my system SSD with HDtuner and it said that it couldn't find any errors. I find it weird that everything is fine after a restart. I use Windows 10. Is there any other solution than reinstalling windows?

Comment: How many SATA devices do you have installed?

Comment: @Ramhound I think about 3 or 4.

Comment: What device is connected to that particular SATA port?  You really need to give us the actual number, information about each device, otherwise your question is difficult to answer.  You need to be editing your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: @Ramhound I have 4. 1 ssd, 2 hhd and 1 dvd-rom

Comment: Which of those devices is connected to SATA port 4?  You really need to be editing your question instead of submitting a comment.  If your question is not edited, to include the information, I won't be able to answer your question given the current provided information.